# R imports not the whole data from csv. How to fix it?

Tags: r, excel, csv, import

I faced an issue of importing data from `csv` file to R.
Some basic information on the file. There are 1941 rows and 78 columns.

When I import data using the following command

```
data = read.csv("data.csv", header = T, sep = ";")
```

I get 824 rows only.

But when I convert the file into the `xlsx` format and then import the `xlsx` file using this command

```
data = read_excel("data.xlsx")
```

everything is ok.

I cannot fix the problem because I don't know where it is.

Can you help me please?

P.S.
Unfortunately I cannot share file eith you as soon as that file is a top secret.

Comment: Have you tried looking at what the last row you get imported and what the first row that doesn't actually contains

Comment: @Dason I looked generally and what I get is that R doesn't import the first 824 rows.

Comment: Have you looked *at the CSV file* using a basic text editor such as Notepad? In my experience, `read.csv` doesn't skip rows for no reason. The issue might actually be your Excel export.

Answer (score 2):

The solution of the problem is to add the parameter `quote=""` in the code like this:

```
data = read.csv("data.csv", header = T, sep = ";", quote = "")
```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Post the error/warning message if any.

Comment: There is no error/warning message. Code works perfectly in terms of syntax but imports not the whole data.

Comment: This is not an answer.  It should be a comment at most.

Answer (score 0):

When you open your data see if you have problematic characters inside columns, like tabs, comas, new lines etc.

I would suggest to read by line as a text file to check the issue.

Without looking onto what in the data causing the problem I guess no one could give you a solution.